# Show table based on dropdown selection angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have Two dropdownlist, one of them will return an array of objects after I select a value from it,

I want to dynamically display the table one the select occurs.

```
 <li class="mat-form-field--inline">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Sélectionner la Réference de l'application</mat-label>
    <select
      [(ngModel)]="selectedObject"
      (change)="getFammille($event.target.value)"
      matNativeControl
    >
      <option
        *ngFor="let application of applications; let i = index"
        [value]="applications[i].reference"
      >
        {{ application.reference }}
      </option>
      &lt;/option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Sélectionner une famille</mat-label>
    <select
      [(ngModel)]="familyName"
      (change)="getCaracteristiques($event.target.value)"
      matNativeControl
    >
      <option
        *ngFor="let famille of familleArray; let i = index"
        [value]="famille.nom"
      >
        {{ famille.nom }}
      </option>
      &lt;/option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>
</li>

// Need to Select this field to display the Table
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Sélectionner une famille</mat-label>
  <select
    [(ngModel)]="familyName"
    (change)="getCaracteristiques($event.target.value)"
    matNativeControl
  >
    <option
      *ngFor="let famille of familleArray; let i = index"
      [value]="famille.nom"
    >
      {{ famille.nom }}
    </option>
    &lt;/option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="this.caracteristiques" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>type</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let carac">{{ carac.type }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="NumeroOrdre">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>champs</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let carac">{{ carac.champs }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Titulaire">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>nom</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let carac">{{ carac.nom }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="UniteCertifie">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>label</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let carac">{{ carac.label }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Etat">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>valeurs</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let carac">{{ carac.valeurs }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

At the moment I have an error because I couldn't figure out a way to ignore the Table before selecting the second field.

Is there way to add this condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to add `*ngIf="caracteristiques"` to `<table..>`:

```
<table  *ngIf="caracteristiques" mat-table [dataSource]="this.caracteristiques"   class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

A full example of the component would be better (html + typescript).